# KDE Plasma and KDE Connect

Tags: kde, android, plasma, kde5, kde-connect

I have kubuntu 16.04 with KDE plasma, kernel 4.6.2. 
I connected android smartphone to KDE via KDE connect feature. Its work fine exclude notification from android to desktop. Notice, that notification from desktop to android work fine. When perform debug process(via tcpdump), I found, that packets from android to desktop is recieved by desktop but not displayed.

Are you can give me tips for resolve this issue?